# Get count in php against unique ID

Tags: php, sql

Need some help.
I have a DB with 4 fields and 1 column of Date of entry with time, as below and i want to get count of last entered values of status against Evaid if it's open or pending.
I tried below code but it's getting last entered value from whole DB - but can't add a logic to get it against the Evaid.

```
DisID   -  Evaid   -   Status
1       -  123     -    Open
2       -  123     -    In Process
3       -  123     -    Close
4       -  2222     -    Open
4       -  2222     -    Open
6       -  2222     -    Closed
7       -  456     -    Open
8       -  456     -    Open
9       -  456     -    Open
10      -  333     -    Open
11      -  333     -    Open

include 'ddmenu.php';
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM disagreements ORDER BY srno DESC LIMIT 1' ) or die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo $row['evaid'];
echo $row['srno'];
}

mysql_free_result($result);
```

Comment: So you want to get count how many are closed and open?

Comment: i want to get count of last entered values of status against Evaid if it's open or pending ///// Simply use where to get the count for closed and open

Comment: "mysql_query()" !!!???!!!  That was deprecated long ago.

Answer (score 0):

As what you are saying - i want to get count of last entered values of status against Evaid if it's open or pending,

You can use where clause to get the count of open and pending status values. See below

> $result = mysql_query('SELECT count(*) as total FROM disagreements
>   WHERE Status = 'open' OR Status = 'In Process' ORDER BY srno DESC
>   LIMIT 1') or die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());